# PHP push and loop array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add a new index to my array of objects and be able to loop and retrieve that new index added.

Currently my array of objects is the following:

```
Array ([0] => 
            stdClass Object ([id] => 4 [date] => 2014-09-08 10:18:10 [status] => 1)
      )
```

So, to loop it I just do:

```
foreach($content as $item){
   echo $item->id;
}
```

But, for some reasons, I need to push a new element to my array:

```
$item  = $data['content']; // $data holds the content above
$clone = array();
foreach($item as $row){

  if($row->status == 1){

     array_push($clone, $row, array("delete" => TRUE));
  }else{

     array_push($clone, $row, array("delete" => FALSE));
  }
}
$item = $clone;
```

And the output is this:

```
Array ( [0] => 
            stdClass Object ([id] => 4 [date] => 2014-09-08 10:18:10 [status] => 1) [1] => Array ( [delete] => 1)
      )
```

But instead I would like something like

```
 Array ( [0] => 
                stdClass Object ([id] => 4 [date] => 2014-09-08 10:18:10 [status] => 1 [delete] => 1) 
          )
```

I also tried:

```
$item[] = (object) array("delete" => FALSE);
```

But the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is enough:

```
foreach($item as $row) {
    $row->delete = ($row->status == 1);
}
```

Comment: it's wrong it won't modify the array because of no refference and it won't put delete property to object when status is not equal to 1.

Comment: @Robert no need to use reference `&` for objects

Comment: @Robert ups sorry I missed the fact OP want to set "false" as well

Comment: yes you're right my bad with refference :) now after you change assigment it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

It's object so set variable as object variable

```
foreach($item as $row)
     $row->delete = $row->status ? true : false;
```